# Can we somehow link to a question on another SE site?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Once in a while, politics related questions that have awesome answers spring up on cousin SE sites (I just ran into [this one](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/33801/332) on History).

Is there any reasonable mechanism to ensure that visitors to Politics.SE can see those questions? Copying them wholesale cross-site seems both stupid and against SE rules. Are there other valid approaches?

Comment: You can [vote for crossover questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/191265) as a new feature and as an item on the [second Stack Exchange Quality Project](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285912/191265).

Comment: @Thunderforge +1, Probably one of the most needed features on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

One possible idea I had (assuming community likes it and moderators don't hate it) is:

1. Create a canonical CW Q&A on main site,

   Q: "What notable/useful questions that are on-topic on Politics.SE were posted across SE network"

   A: List of links
2. Create a Meta Q&A, with the question being about same idea, and 1 link per answer

   An answer with a link to SE post has to gain X # of votes before being allowed onto main site's canonical Q&A

   Make this Meta Q&A "featured", to give visibility to more site users.

Comment: I don't think that this is very useful, because people who search the site about a specific topic are not very likely to stumble upon that CW question.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if we tried this on Meta. I'm not so sure about taking it to the main site though, I wouldn't want to create the impression that every other possible "What notable/useful ..." question is welcomed here.

Comment: @Philipp - do you have statistics that show that THAT is how users mainly get to the site's information (as opposed to, for example, browsing "most voted questions" view)? I know I did that on SO, as well as several other sites, and many users are known to anecdotally do so.

Comment: @Yannis - yes, definitely a valid concern. I'm more of a thought that this is the fault of my poor wording in this proposal than the underlying idea, though, so any improvement to the wording is welcome.

Comment: It's not so much the wording, it's that we'd be opening the doors to "big list" questions. The canonical example to this is the "Hidden features of ..." questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hidden+features (plus a million more deleted ones).